# MATLAB append two arrays(one string cell and one numeric vector) into a .csv

Tags: arrays, matlab, csv, export-to-csv

I have two arrays, X and Y

X has numeric data like this:

`12342
1355
2324
...`

Y has strings like this:

`APPLE
METRO
BLANKET
...`

I want to append these arrays into a pre-existing .csv in this format:

`X(1,1), Y{1,1}
X(2,1), Y{2,1}
X(3,1), Y{2,1}
...`

How should I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately writing cell arrays to csvs can be tricky. One way or another you need to loop through so you can access the data within each cell. The reason for cells not writing automatically is that a cell can contain anything - like a whole matrix of data.

The most versatile way that will allow for any types of cell/matrix combos is to use fprintf - you just need to specify a format.
http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html

```
nrows = size(x,1);
fid = fopen('newfile.csv','w');
for aa = 1 : nrows
    fprintf(fid,'%f,%s\r\n', x(aa,1), y{aa,1});
end
```

you can use  %d instead of %f if you are only chasing decimal numbers instead of floating point precision.

I have found fprintf to be faster than any of the alternatives for this sort of situation. It is a little more low-level but allows you to write anything you like to file.